# Using catel with 3rd party controls

Tags: wpf, mvvm, catel

I'm new to catel and mvvm. I 've successfully built a sample application the "catel" way and I like all the added features which I do need (thank you for the great tutorials). I've successfully run a sample app using typical mvvm and a 3rd party control printing reports. When I tried to use the 3rd party control in the catel application I had issues making it work, even with the information provided in catels' documentation. Even if I do manage it to work, I don't want to make custom base classes to add new controls, because most of my controls are special (3D). So, my question: can I use all of the catel features, including model and viewmodel capabilities, but use external windows and controls with the typical manual binding procedure? Do I need to know of any special concerns?

Comment: This is way too unclear to answer.  You need to create a simple application that demonstrates your problem. Post the code in a question with details about why it isn't working.

Comment: Hi Will and thank you for your reply. I'm not asking why it doesn't work. I probably know what to do to make it work (I need to create a base class with added behavior). My question is if I can use catel for the model and for the viewmodel, but use 3rd party windows+controls with manually adding the binding. Do I need to ALWAYS create a base class and implement IDataWindow and IUserControl to make it work with catel? Or can I use it as is and loose some automation?

Comment: You can easily use Catel *without* the logic in the view. But.... you will miss a few important features such as nested user controls, Save / Cancel view model and other stuff. It will be more like a "regular" view model as in any other fx.

Comment: Thank you Geert van Horrik. That is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I learn catel since 2 weeks too, welcome into the Catel World :)

So, you can create custom window base class with IDataWindow and your window inherit Catel features. Need more coding but not a lot !

I suggest you to consult the excellent documentation here for [Custom Window](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+a+custom+window) and here for [Custom Control](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+a+custom+control)

Hope it's help !
Dams

Comment: Thank you Damosse31. I intent to use 100% external controls/windows and I try to avoid making that to all controls. I want catel for validation, IoC, undo, xamarin etc. I guess it's better work on plain mvvm and add each needed feature seperately.

Comment: You don't have to create a base class for *every* control, you only need 1 for your user control and 1 for a window.